# Do we need to edit ApplicationConfig.java in netbeans?

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, jetty

I am using netbeans and in my application Applicationconfig.java says

> /**
>        * Do not modify this method. It is automatically generated by NetBeans REST support.
>   */

Right now I am trying to deploy my rest based service out of netbeans+glassfish to my local machine on jetty and I am not able to access services after deploying it. So i suspect the problem is in ApplicationConfig.java since I am not using any web.xml for servlet mapping .

Is Applicationconfig.java updated automatically in generated .war as well?
thanks for help...

this is how my applicationconfig.java looks like:

```
package org.netbeans.rest.application.config;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("webresources")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return getRestResourceClasses();
    }

    /**
     * Do not modify this method. It is automatically generated by NetBeans REST support.
     */
    private Set<Class<?>> getRestResourceClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<Class<?>>();
        resources.add(cribservice.Cribservice.class);
        return resources;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So before deploying your project on jetty out of netbeans. First make sure you have all the related jetty-web.xml and other required files.

In order to generate these files , install jetty plugin for netbeans, Download jetty server from internet Create a new project , select jetty as a server and point it to location of jetty. Then create your project , test it and deploy it after you paste your generated .war in /webapps folder